# XMLHttpRequest don't include GET request

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to retrieve JSON data using `XMLHttpRequest` but it seems like it won't include any of my field data.

```
var fields = ["ID", "item_id", "item_tag", "item_name", "item_default_price", "item_quantity", "item_comment"];

function loadTable(json_items) {
  alert(json_items);
}

var frm = document.querySelector("form.inventory-search-form");
frm.onsubmit = function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.onreadystatechange = function () {
      var DONE = this.DONE || 4;
      if (this.readyState === DONE && this.status == 200){
        try {
          loadTable(JSON.parse(this.responseText));
        } catch(err) {

        }
      }
  };

  request.open('GET', '/api/inventory/list', true);
  request.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');  // Tells server that this call is made for ajax purposes.
                                                                   // Most libraries like jQuery/Prototype/Dojo do this
  var data = new FormData(frm);
  for (i=0; i<fields.length; i++) {
    data.append(fields[i], frm.querySelector("[name='" + fields[i] + "']").value);
  }

  request.send(data);
}

frm.onsubmit(document.createEvent("Event"));
```

What did I do wrong?

I have checked the `FormData` and it contained the fields, but it didn't make the required GET request such as `/api/inventory/list?ID=2` instead it only issued `/api/inventory/list`.

Thanks!

Comment: [`XMLHttpRequest.send()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/send): _"If the request **method is GET** or HEAD, **the argument is ignored** and request body is set to null."_

Comment: @Andreas So how should I pass the data? Through the URL? Don't we have a more efficient/easier way to pass the data?

Comment: "Through the URL?" — Yes

Comment: "Don't we have a more efficient/easier way to pass the data?" — Query strings are not inefficient, nor are they particularly difficult to encode (even if you don't bother using a library)

Comment: `var queryString = fields.map(field => encodeURIComponent(field) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(frm.querySelector("[name='" + fields[i] + "']").value)).join("&")`